# Flyway migration error after flyway:baseline

Tags: postgresql, maven, flyway

I used Java+Spring+Maven+Flyway+Postgres in my pet project.
Here two sql files in db/migration.
When I first time run application with

```
mvn spring-boot:run
```

or before application start use

```
mvn flyway:migrate -Dflyway.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/university -Dflyway.user=tester -Dflyway.password=test
```

Db was created corret, whithout any error, but when I want to create V1 at first with

```
 mvn flyway:baseline -Dflyway.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/university -Dflyway.user=tester -Dflyway.password=test
```

and after that:

```
mvn flyway:migrate -Dflyway.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/university -Dflyway.user=tester -Dflyway.password=test
```

I catch error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.flywaydb:flyway-maven-plugin:6.4.4:migrate (default-cli) on project universityschedule: org.flywaydb.core.internal.command.DbMigrate$FlywayMigrateException: 
[ERROR] Migration V2__add_email_and_phone_to_person.sql failed
[ERROR] ------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] SQL State  : 42P01
[ERROR] Error Code : 0
[ERROR] Message    : ERROR: relation "public.teacher" does not exist
```

Why does it happens? How to fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flyway baseline is to be used with non-empty databases. In this situation the first migration is assumed to represent the sql required to create the database to its current state. As a result, its assuming your `V1` migration is not intended to be executed, and just marks it as the `baseline`.

If you just migrate, skipping the baseline step, it should work fine.